# Fetch and dispaly through a modal database contents of selected in a datatable row when button is click

Tags: php, ajax, jquery-ui

I have a datatable which retrieves data from db, i want to be to implement a modal pop up under the row improvement actions so instead displaying the actual improvement actions i want like a symbol under that row so when i click it a modal appears with the improvement actions while all the other data remains the same , i want to implement this using ajax but am quite a novice in ajax please assist.

```
<table class="table  table-hover   table-striped table-bordered datatable-basic"  >
                                        <thead>

                                            <tr>

                                                <tr class="bg-violet-400" >

                              <th>ID</th>
                                                <th>Site</th>
                                                <th>Date</th>
                                                <th>SN</th>
                                                <th>Gap identified</th>
                                                <th>Improvement Actions</th>
                                                <th>Timeline</th>
                                                <th>Person responsible</th>
                                                <th>Status</th>



                                            </tr>

                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                         <?php
                          $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "dqa");
                                        $query=mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM action_plan");

                                        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
                                        {
                                            ?>
                         <tr>
                         <td><?php echo $row['id'] ?></td>
                                     <td><?php echo $row['site'] ?></td>
                                     <td><?php echo $row['date'] ?></td>
                                      <td><?php echo $row['sn']  ?></td>
                                     <td><?php echo $row['gap_identified'] ?></td>
                                     <td><?php echo $row['Improvement_Actions'] ?></td>
                                     <td><?php echo $row['timeline'] ?></td>
                                     <td><?php echo $row['person_responsible'] ?></td>
                                     <td><?php if( $row['status'] == 1  )

                                     {
                                    echo '  <button type="button" class="btn bg-grey">Approved</button></span>';

                                    }


             elseif( $row['status'] == 0  ) {
                echo '  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Active Action</button></span>';
                }
                elseif( $row['status'] == 2  ) {

                 echo ' <button type="button" class="btn bg-brown"> Resubmission </button></span>';

                }
                    elseif( $row['status'] == 3  ) {
                echo '  <button type="button" class="btn bg-orange">Action Due</button></span>';

            }


                         ?></td></td>


                                     </tr>

                                    <?php
                                        }



                                      ?>



                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>

                                </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Can you provide any of the jQuery you have attempted so far? This is also not a very complete example, it's hard to determine what you are trying to accomplish. Consider using jsfiddle with just the outputted HTML from your PHP Script.

Comment: @Twisty find the jsfiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/isaiahakello/u2ntdhua/

Comment: This fiddle should not include any PHP and does not provide any sample data to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any sample data or example data, I can only speculate at what you are trying to accomplish. Here is an example that I think you may find helpful.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".table").DataTable();
  $(".table tbody .actions").button({
    showLabel: false,
    icon: "ui-icon-extlink"
  }).click(function(e) {
    var self = $(this);
    var row = $(this).attr("href").substring(1);
    var siteurl = "<?php echo siteurl('improvement');?>";
    var form = $("<form>", {
      id: "form-" + row
    });
    form.append($("<input>", {
      type: "hidden",
      name: "rowid",
      value: row
    }));
    var dialog = $("<div>", {
      title: "Improvement Actions - Row " + row
    }).append(form).dialog({
      modal: true,
      create: function(e, ui) {
        $.getJSON(siteurl + "/" + row, function(data) {
          $('[name="rowid"]', this).val(data.id);
        });
      },
      close: function(e, ui) {
        self.data("results", form.serialize());
        dialog.dialog("destroy").remove();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<table class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered datatable-basic">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <tr class="bg-violet-400">
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Site</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>SN</th>
        <th>Gap identified</th>
        <th>Improvement Actions</th>
        <th>Timeline</th>
        <th>Person responsible</th>
        <th>Status</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        1
      </td>
      <td>
        LOC-1
      </td>
      <td>
        04/24/2018
      </td>
      <td>
        1001
      </td>
      <td>
        0.1
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="#1" class="button actions">Improvement Actions</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        &nbsp;
      </td>
      <td>
        John Smith
      </td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn bg-grey">Approved</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Assuming you are using DataTable, The table is populated with various data from PHP, resulting in HTML like shown above. You can then use jQuery UI to program the button to build a dialog. One of the callback events for `.dialog()` is `create`, see more: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-create

You can perform your AJAX call at this time to get specific data for this dialog. In my example, all of it is being created dynamically, so there is no need to reset forms etc.

I advise using `$.getJSON()`, but there is nothing wrong with the `$.ajax()` code you implemented. The `$.getJSON()` simply assumes you are performing a GET call to a resource that will return JSON data. Resulting in simplified code.

Testing of this example is not complete as the PHP Script URL is fake or will be `null`.

Hope that helps.